# Mass create txt file in each folder

Tags: windows, scripting

I have a directory with a bunch of folders and I want to create a text file for each folder containing this string: Visit http://www.example.com. How can I do this with windows cmd?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually fairly simple to do given a short string like that:

```
for /d %M in (E:\somdir\*) do echo "yourstring" > E:\somdir\%M\stringfile.txt
```

The `/d` flag tells for to do 'directories in the path

%M stands in for the directories being iterated over.

(e:\somdir*) is the path to be iterated over.

Everything after the `do` is the command it executes, using %M for each item iterated over.

Answer (score -1):

Afaik, simple cmd does not provide the same power as bash or power shell.
The most easiest way working on severall platforms is by using a macro-like language,
looping through the directories and put the textfile.
I suggest to use AutoIT - http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Its VERY WELL documentaded and has much effort with just a few lines of code.
Check the following helps:

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileCopy.htm

http://dailycupoftech.com/folder-recursion-in-autoit/

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions.htm

It should not take more then 10 lines of code to do what you want.